# Heroku - EmberJS - Deploy fail ( Unable download node )

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js

when I try to push code on Heroku, the build/deploy fail because of node problem.

**Console log**

```
cd dungeon-diary
heroku buildpacks:set https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/emberjs.tgz   
git push heroku master
```

**Output console with error**

```
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> emberjs app detected
    remote: -----> Setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false to install ember-cli toolchain
    remote: -----> Fetching buildpack heroku/nodejs-v98
    remote: -----> Node.js detected
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
    remote:        
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
    remote:        NODE_ENV=production
    remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Installing binaries
    remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.* || >= 12
    remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.x
    remote:        
    remote:        Resolving node version 10.* || >= 12 via semver.io...
    remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.7.0...
    remote:        Unable to download node 14.7.0; does it exist?** 
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Build failed
```

**package.json**

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.* || >= 12"
  },
```

Comment: Node 14.7.0 exists, this may be an issue with heroku. You may want to limit heroku to using node 12.x to get around this. To do so, change the engines string in package.json to "10.* || 12.*"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was...

in the log you can see, the console choose node 14.7.0 by itself,
but for Heroku it was unacceptable. So I had to explicitly write which version use ( to avoid 14.7.0 ) and it starts work :)

...weird for me why console choose the unsupported version :)