# How to resolve "Unable to download node 14.18.0" when deploying an Ember.js app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, ember.js

I encountered the error mentioned in the Title.

I have referred to a few relevant Heroku articles and tried their suggested changes including specifying the exact version of Node.js, Yarn, or npm that I'm using locally , but that still didn't work.

Here's the relevant sections extracted from my `package.json`:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.0",
    "npm": "6.14.15",
    "yarn": "1.19.1"
  },
  "ember": {
    "edition": "octane"
  }
```

Here's the deployment log:

```
Enumerating objects: 1134, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1134/1134), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1027/1027), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1134/1134), 309.32 KiB | 2.64 MiB/s, done.
Total 1134 (delta 581), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/emberjs.tgz
remote: -----> emberjs app detected
remote: -----> Setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false to install ember-cli toolchain
remote: -----> Fetching buildpack heroku/nodejs-v98
remote: -----> Node.js detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  14.18.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.15
remote:
remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.18.0...
remote:        Unable to download node 14.18.0; does it exist?
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote: -----> Failed trying to compile heroku/nodejs-v98
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile emberjs app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs during the build process? Look at them it will be of great help.

Comment: May I know is there a more detailed log than the one that I extracted from the console and attached in my question? If so, may I know how to access such log?

Comment: Have you installed the heroku-cli? There is command which can fetch you logs. Check [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

Comment: Based on the link you shared, I checked the build log under Activity tab. It happened to be the same as the log shown on my console, which I extracted and attached in my question. I think the gist of it was:
Unable to download node 14.18.0; does it exist?

Comment: this is an old article, but specifying an older version of node may work: https://help.heroku.com/6235QYN4/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-no-matching-node-versions (not 6 or anything like that, but maybe an earlier v14)

Comment: looks like this happens for nearly every node release... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245919/heroku-emberjs-deploy-fail-unable-download-node

Comment: Indeed an older version of 12.x, i.e. 12.16.3 worked. There should be an older version of 14.x and 16.x that might work. I tried to search but unfortunately couldn't find any Heroku pages that mention specific version numbers that they support.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support), versions `12.x`, `14.x`, and `16.x` are supported.

When such version numbers are literally specified in `package.json` file, during the Heroku build process, those will be resolved to the latest patch version, e.g. `12.22.7`, `14.18.1`, and `16.13.0` respectively as of the time of writing.

Somehow Heroku was unable to download the latest version of every major series.

In my original question, I used version `14.18.0` in my local and that version was specified in `package.json`. It appears that Heroku was also not able to download that version.

I double checked this [Heroku Help page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#compare-node-and-npm-versions) and noticed version `12.16.3` is given in the example when illustrating how to compare Node and npm versions. I updated my `package.json` to use `12.16.3` and retried the the deployment and it was successful.

I tried to search but unfortunately I couldn't find any Heroku Help page that specifies the exact Node.js version numbers that they support.